# What does a semicolon before the query string mean in a URL?

Tags: url, https, hyperlink

I have read about URL syntax on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.2?topic=concepts-components-url).

I understand that any URL should be of the same form of a generic URI, which is:

```
URI = scheme ":" ["//" authority] path ["?" query] ["#" fragment]
```

Now I have this apparently valid URL:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/mybucket;tab=objects?prefix=&forceOnObjectsSortingFiltering=false
```

which has a `;` semicolon before the `?` character which marks the beginning of the `query` string, supposedly indicating that it's somehow part of the `path`. I have googled "URL path syntax" and have found nothing related to my question. What does a `;` semicolon symbol mean at that position? What does `tab=objects` do?

Comment: It`s part of the path.  It doesn't have any special global meaning.  Any special meaning would be application specific.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about understanding URLs.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Have I posted this question on the wrong stack exchange site?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a right stack exchange for this.